# What is the difference between standard attributes and GNU "__attribute__"s?

Tags: c++, gcc, attributes

Note that this question is about **C++** so the following question does not apply to me.

[__attribute__ in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458573/attribute-in-c)

Plus the top answer only consists of links and doesn't really explain anything. [GCC attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html#Attribute-Syntax), of the form __attribute__((*attribute-list*)) are an extension in C but exist in C++ mode too. Of course, C++ also has attributes which I refer to as "standard attributes". The two seem to be completely different, so I am asking for a summary of the primary differences and how they interact.

- When should I use one over the other?
- Is there any point to using __attribute__ in C++?

Comment: If you can, use the standard ones for maximum portability. If you have to, use the extension to get the work done.

Comment: I agree with @Deduplicator, use the standard (of which there are very few) when possible, otherwise if you really need a specific attribute just use it. The nice thing about how the GCC (remember that GCC has been backronymed to GNU Compiler Collection, it doesn't stand (anymore) for GNU C Compiler) has its attributes designed is that it should be easy to define a preprocessor macro of them, so it's easy to conditionally use them only on compliant compilers (which includes clang and ICC).

Answer (score 1):

The reasons for having two sets of attribute annotations are primarily historical. C and C++ lacked methods for expressing useful code annotations like `likely` or `fallthrough` so each compiler vendor invented his own extensions to support whatever was requested by customers (Visual Studio used `__declspec` and GNU used `__attribute__`). Recently we also got C++11 attributes to make this even messier.

For C++11-only code you should probly use new standard syntax. For everything else (C or pre-C++11 clients) you better off using traditional portability macro in your library's header:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
# define MYLIB_NOINLINE __attribute__((noinline))
#elif defined _MSC_VER
# define MYLIB_NOINLINE __declspec(noinline)
#else
# error Unknown compiler
#endif
```